# Margin-top collapsing issue

Tags: html, css

I might just not understand basic CSS and HTML but this is aggravating me to no end. I have a "test" div inside a "content" div that I want to have a margin-top of 10px NOT padding as in I want to push the entire "test" element down by 10 pixels. margin-top seems to be the answer but it's not pushing from the parent element, but from the top of the page.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
body {
  background-color: #336699;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #336699;
}
#container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
#content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#test {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="test">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're witnessing [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). Simply add `overflow:auto;` to `#content`.

```
#content {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uHdg3/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just move the #test element down then add padding-top: 10px to its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

set #Container to have a position:absolute; and then set the elements you wish to use margin-top to have position:relative

Answer (score 0):

You're having a problem called collapsing - margins. 
Just to make sure you're not doing anything else wrong, add the following code:

```
*, *:after, *:before{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

This will make sure your box model is the correct one.
And add overflow auto to content.

Here's a demo with your stuff fixed.

http://codepen.io/yisera/pen/qizwt/